# What is the correct way to use 全部: Adverbially or Attributively?

Tags: adverbial, attributive

Which of the following two versions is correct? Or are both of them incorrect?

> The one who ate all nuts was Squirrel.
>
> 木の実を全部に食べたのりすです。
>
> 全部な木の実を食べたのりすです。

Comment: Of potential value:https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/placing-a-quantifier-between-a-noun-and-particle and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/positioning-of-quantities-using-counters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both, kind of. It's an adverbial noun (noun that can behave like an adverb), so you can treat it like you would any other number + counter.

So your first sentence is almost correct (skip the に):

> 木の実を全部食べたのはりすです。

Alternatively, you can use の instead to use it attributively (but not な):

> 全部の木の実を食べたのはりすです。

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  If the word was different, e.g. 半分 would it be used in the same manner or is there something specific about 全部?

Comment: @Nutkin it kind of depends on the word, but 半分 in particular I think works the same. Check a dictionary like Jisho and see if it says adverbial noun.