# What is the actual nuance of 初だし here?

Tags: reading-comprehension, multiple-readings

[image]

Context: This is a box from a video game artwork, where the director describes the creation of the character. Most of it is clear to me, however toward the end I run into this puzzling line:

The line in question

> (...) 他キャラが落ち着いているので、その分感情を動かす立ち回りが多いです。フレッシュ担当なので、初だし絶対がっつ いてるよね! と、回数も多く指定させてもらいました(笑)。

Because it has no furigana, I'm not sure about the actual meaning of 初だし . I understand 初出 can mean "first appearance" but also it's possible that it's the meaning "innocent; naive; unsophisticated; inexperienced; green; wet behind the ears" + だ　し。

I understand "、回数も多く指定させてもらいました(笑)。" is the director own words: I took the liberty of pointing out many times.

My guess is that he's describing the character's attitude and how he must be, however I'm stuck on what "フレッシュ担当なので、初だし絶対がっついてるよね" could mean.

Answer (score 1):

This 初だし is 初【はつ】だ (It's the first time), followed by [し as a reason marker](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28096/5010). Here, 初 is a no-adjective meaning "first (event/experience)". (初出 is almost always written in kanji.)

The last part is saying something like this (brackets added for clarity):

> フレッシュ担当なので、「初だし絶対がっついてるよね!」と、回数も多く指定させてもらいました(笑)。
>
> Since he is in charge of freshness, I thought "It's his first time so he must be really eager!", and took the liberty to make sure he'd get a lot of "turns(/scenes/etc)"!

Note that 回数を多く指定する is not "point out many times" but "specify a large number of times/turns (regarding him)". What 回数 actually refers to seems to be intentionally made vague in this text. You need to infer it from the content or genre of the game.

Comment: h, I ses. Likely it's a joke on how the character is very present in the narrative and keeps being inserted in scenes though the game.

Though why isn't 回数も多く an adverb for 指定させて?

Comment: @Kawase_K 多く *is* an adverbial modifier that modifies 指定する. It's similar to たくさん注文する, 本を色々読む, 猫が多くいる, etc.

Comment: Just in case, 指定 and 指摘 are different words.

Comment: Yes, but said 回数 is not acting as an adverb here? What I mean is 多く is about how he 指定させて right? And not    回数 are 多く?

Comment: @Kawase_K 回数 is the direct object of 指定する. "回数を指定する" means "to specify the number of times", and "回数を多く指定する" means "to specify a large number of times". Here, を happens to be replaced with も meaning "also". 多く is an adverb, and [its grammar is explained here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21549/5010). There's really nothing different from 本を3冊読む, 本を多く読む, 本を多く注文する, etc.

Comment: Ah I see. My confusion was that I took 多く指定する as "Designed many times" but instead it's about the 回数 are  多く?

Comment: @Kawase_K You're right. Note that the primary meaning of 多く is "a large number/amount" rather than "many times".